# PHP & Javascript Issue - SyntaxError: Cannot declare a const variable twice: 'map'

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to populate a google map with a list of long/lat from a JSON file and having this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Error] SyntaxError: Cannot declare a const variable twice: 'map'.

[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

```
    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
        <script
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
          async
        ></script>
        <script>
        
            // Initialize and add the map
            function initMap() {
              // The location of Uluru
              const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
              // The map, centered at Uluru
              const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 5,
                center: uluru,
              });
              // The marker, positioned at Uluru
              
              <?php
                $data = json_decode($eaterJSON,true);
                $data = array_values( array_unique( $data, SORT_REGULAR ) );
                $clean = json_encode($data);
                // print_r($clean);
              
                foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                
                const map = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: <?php echo $value['lat'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $value['lon'] ?>},
                    map: map,
                  });
                  
                  
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                
            }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename the second **map** const to **marker**:

From: `const map = new google.maps.Marker({`
to: `const marker = new google.maps.Marker({`

**UPDATE:**
Oh, wait! You generate JS codes (markers) with PHP loop this cause multiple same variable names! Please learn more about (multiple) marker creation!

In this case you no need to assign a marker to a variable, simply create markers in loop:

```
    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
    <script>
    
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
          // The location of Uluru
          const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
          // The map, centered at Uluru
          const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: uluru,
          });
          // The marker, positioned at Uluru
          
          <?php
            $data = json_decode($eaterJSON,true);
            $data = array_values( array_unique( $data, SORT_REGULAR ) );
            $clean = json_encode($data);
            // print_r($clean);
          
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: <?php echo $value['lat'] ?>, lng: <?php echo $value['lon'] ?>},
                map: map,
              });
              
              
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            
        }

</script>
```